# How do I find the treasure in the Silent Church section of Aquan Ruins(3-5)?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

Under similar circumstances as my [Lava Pool treasure hunt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27040/how-do-i-get-the-treasure-in-the-lava-pools-section-of-ignan-ruins2-3), I find myself poking and stabbing at random enemies and objects in Chantelise, hoping to uncover another hidden treasure. This time, however, I took the deep dive and bought myself a hint at the cost of my life force.

> It says that I have to "punish that trickster. Again."

This is in reference to...

> ...the hint for 3-4, "punish that trickster", where I simply had to jump on all eight tombstones in the graveyard.

However, in spite of knowing this, I don't really get what I'm supposed to be doing this time around. I've run around hitting random objects that seem out of place and killed each jellyfish individually, yet I don't seem to have found anything secret at all.

How do I find this treasure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as with the last one, you need to get an unusual enemy to spawn. And, just like the last one, you get it to spawn through some vandalism.

**You need to break all of the torches in the room**. They take 3 hits to take out, so you may've passed them off as indestructible. Normally I'm an advocate of getting the treasures then clearing the room, but with that big Bomb there you might want to clear the room out first. At any rate, once you've broken the last one, hey, look who decides to show up?

[image: Unique fish enemy spawns]

This opponent is non-elemental, so you won't get an elemental bonus against it. However, it only has about 50 HP, so it dies quite easily. **Defeat this fish** to win the following prize.

> A Silver Gauntlet! It gives you +40 attack. Simple, yet reliable.